# Python - create a new dataframe out of each line in a big dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

## Code:

```
x=1
for x in len(df_prep.index):
    coinsymbol=df_prep.loc[x,'symbol']
    df+coinsymbol= df_prep.loc[x,:]
    x+=1
```

## Aim:

Make new dataframes with the name of the x-line value from the 
column symbol and save in it all values of the row.
Each day i get new data, so i want them to append on the respective 
frame, associated by the 'symbol'column-value

## Error:

```
File "<ipython-input-22-59737c45ac15>", line 15
    df+coinsymbol= df_prep.loc[x,:]
    ^
SyntaxError: can't assign to operator
```

thx in advance

Comment: Well it's what is written. You can't use a '+' on the left hand side of an assignment. So this is an error of the syntax. What do you want to achieve with that line?

Comment: If the data is coming in every day, surely it's in the same format? Why not just keep all of the data in one `DataFrame` and then use boolean masking at the end to create the respective sub-symbol dataframes? `temp = [df_prep.loc[df_prep.symbol==i, :] for i in df_prep.symbol.unique()]` gives you a list of dataframes for each symbol..

Comment: @Aloiiz thx a lot!very smart line.

Comment: my next line looks like this now:logs = temp[i].append(temp[i]) for i in len(temp) , but doesnt make much sense, i need a variable to append all new rows, every hour when the script runs by a crontab ( associated to the right dataframe, data come in clean json but the order isnt the same)